# Pushing data values of a multiple select Only pushes the first clicked option multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, html

I came accross a problem while using Javascript . I have a multiple `select` who I want to get all the data-type selected then push it to an array . But I got stuck in the first step of getting the data selected. It only Gets the first option selected then when i click on the other one it pushes again the same first value.

Here is my code :

```
<select  multiple  id="boox" name="box[]" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true"  data-size="4"  required> 
    <option value="1" data-type="11">item 1 </option>
    <option value="2" data-type="22">item 2 </option>
    <option value="3" data-type="33">item 3 </option>
    <option value="4" data-type="44">item 4 </option>
</select>
```

My Javascript Code :

```
var options = [];
$('#box').change(function() {
    options.push($('#box').find("option:selected").data("type"));
    console.log(options);
});
```

For example if I select item 2 it returns in the console :

> 22

Then If I click on item 3 , it returns :

> 22,22

I Hope someone could clarify what I am doing wrong.I will appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to loop through all the selected options and push the value to your options array. In below code I use jQuery `each()` function to loop through all the selected options and store their value in options array:

```js
var options =[];
 $('#box').change(function(){
  options =[];
  $('#box').find("option:selected").each(function(){
    options.push($(this).data("type"));
  })
  console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  multiple  id="box" name="box[]" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true"  data-size="4"  required> 
<option value="1" data-type="11">item 1 </option>
<option value="2" data-type="22">item 2 </option>
<option value="3" data-type="33">item 3 </option>
<option value="4" data-type="44">item 4 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Very much Sir ! it solved my problem I appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this. Use change event  and then access value.

```js
var optVal = [];
var tempVal = [];

$(".box").change(function() {
  
  $(".box option").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
  var tempVal = $(".box").val();
  
  if(tempVal.indexOf(val) >= 0 && optVal.indexOf(val) < 0) {
    optVal.push(val);
    console.log("Opt: " + optVal);
  } else if(tempVal.indexOf(val) < 0 && optVal.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
    optVal.splice(optVal.indexOf(val) , 1);
    console.log("Opt: " + optVal);
  }
  
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  multiple  class="box" name="box[]" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true"  data-size="4"  required> 
<option value="1" data-type="11">item 1 </option>
<option value="2" data-type="22">item 2 </option>
<option value="3" data-type="33">item 3 </option>
<option value="4" data-type="44">item 4 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but still have the sae problem.but this time he can't access the method click. I used  `$('#box option').on("click",function(){}` since the option box I created using javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir ! I appreciate your help . My code works now thanks to all of you .

Comment: Welcome buddy :)